# データベースにデータを登録することが出来ない。

Tags: mysql

PHPでECサイトを作成しております。
データベースにデータを登録する処理を作成したにもかかわらず、
データが登録できない状態になっております。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一応var_dumpで該当データの中身を確認したり、
処理を修正したり、SQL文のスペルなどを確認しました。
その結果、$_POSTの中身には値が入っていることが判明しました。
明確な仮説として、INSERT文の中身が間違っているのではないかと考えています。
更に、Notice: Undefined indexとNotice: Undefined variableエラーも発生しました。
phpMyAdminで該当のSQLを実行しましたが、エラーが発生しました。

```
エラー
SQL クエリ:


INSERT INTO item(name, price, img, status, created_date, updated_date) VALUES('テスト','130','','0','2021-11-18 11:39:42','2021-11-18 11:39:42')
MySQL のメッセージ: ドキュメント

#1062 - '0' は key 'PRIMARY' において重複しています
```

また、CREATE文の書き方がわからないので、itemテーブルの構造は直接テキストで書きます。

```
    #   名前  データ型    照合順序    属性  NULL    デフォルト値  コメント    その他 操作
    1   id主 int(11)         いいえ なし          変更 変更   削除 削除   
その他 その他
    2   name    varchar(20) utf8_general_ci     いいえ なし          変更 変更   削除 削除   
その他 その他
    3   price   int(11)         いいえ なし          変更 変更   削除 削除   
その他 その他
    4   img varchar(20) utf8_general_ci     いいえ なし          変更 変更   削除 削除   
その他 その他
    5   status  int(11)         いいえ なし          変更 変更   削除 削除   
その他 その他
    6   created_date    datetime            いいえ なし          変更 変更   削除 削除   
その他 その他
    7   updated_date    datetime            いいえ なし          変更 変更   削除 削除   
その他 その他
```

お手数をおかけしますがデータベースのデータの保存の仕方、エラーの直し方について、ご教授お願い致します。

ソースコード
functions.php

```
 <?php
 require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');

function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_item($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
        }
        
           var_dump($_POST['new_name']);
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
            
        }
        
           var_dump($_POST['new_price']);
        
         if ($_FILES['new_img']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

            if (count($err_msg) === 0) {

                $chk_picture = getimagesize($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name']);

                if ($chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/png' || $chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {

                    if ($chk_picture[0] <= 500 && ($chk_picture[1] <= 500)) {

                        $mime = $chk_picture['mime'];
                        switch ($mime) {
                            case 'image/png':
                                $type = '.png';
                                break;
                            case 'image/jpeg':
                                $type = '.jpg';
                                break;
                        }

                        $upload = $uploaddir . date('YmdHis') . rand(0, 10000) . $type;
                        
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name'], $upload);
                    } else {
                        $err_msg[] = 'ファイルは縦と横500px以内にしてください';
                    }
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'PNGかJPEG形式のファイルをアップロードしてください';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = 'ファイルを選択してください';
        }

        
        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
        if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
             
             $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
        }
            
        }
        var_dump($_POST['new_status']);
    
        
            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        var_dump($new_time);
            
            
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO item(name, price, img, status, created_date, updated_date) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_img.'\',\''.$new_status.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\')';
          var_dump($sql);
            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
                return $err_msg;
                
                
            }
                
            }
    }


        
// function update_drink($link) {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

//         if (isset($_POST['stock']) === TRUE) {
            
//                 $update_stock = (int)($_POST['stock']);

//                 $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//                 $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

//                 $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $update_id;
                
//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
//                 } else {
//                   $err_msg[] = 'DBエラーが発生しました。';
//                   return $err_msg;
//                 }
//                 }
//         }
// }

// function update_drink2($link) {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {
//     if (isset($_POST['stock']) === TRUE) {
//     $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
//     FROM drink_info_table WHERE status = 1 AND drink_id ='  . $change_id;
//     $sql= 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET stock  = stock -1 WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;
//     $data = [];
//     mysqli_query($link, $sql);
//         }
// }
// }

// function update_drink3($link) {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {
//     $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//     $update_time =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
//     FROM drink_info_table WHERE status = 1 AND drink_id ='  . $change_id;
//     $sql= 'INSERT INTO drink_history_table(drink_id, purchased_at) VALUES(\''.$change_id.'\',\''.$update_time.'\')';
//     $data = [];
//     mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        
// }
// }





// function change_drink($link) {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

//         if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
//             if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
//                 $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//                 $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

//                 $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//                 $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
                    
//                 } else {
//                     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
//                 return $err_msg;
//             }
//         }
//     }
    
// }



function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT item.name, item.price, item.img, item.status, item.created_date, item.updated_date FROM item';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

// function names_sql($link) {
//     $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
//     FROM drink_info_table WHERE status = 1 AND drink_id ='  . $change_id;
//     $data = [];
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
//      foreach ($data as $info) {
//               $drink_name = $info['drink_name'];
//      }
//     return $drink_name;
// }

// function prices_sql($link) {
//     $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
//     FROM  drink_info_table WHERE status = 1  AND drink_id ='  . $change_id;
//     $data = [];
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
//      foreach ($data as $info) {
//                 $price = (int) $info['price'];
//                 $money = $_POST['money'];
//                 $return = $money - $price;
//      }
//          return $return;
// }

// function prices_check_sql($link)  {
//     if (!empty($_POST['drink_id'])) {
//     $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
//     FROM  drink_info_table WHERE status = 1  AND drink_id ='  . $change_id;
//     $data = [];
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
//     foreach ($data as $info) {
//                 $price = (int) $info['price'];
//                 $money = $_POST['money'];
//                 if ($price > $money) {
//                 $err_msg = 'お金が足りません。';
//                 return $err_msg;
//     }
//   }
//  }

// }


// function does_sql($link) {
//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
//     FROM drink_info_table WHERE status = 1';
//     $data = [];
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
//     return $data;
// }

// function stock_check($link) {
//     if (!empty($_POST['drink_id'])) {
//     $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.stock, drink_info_table.status
//     FROM drink_info_table WHERE status = 1 AND drink_id ='  . $change_id;
//     $data = [];
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
//   foreach ($data as $info) {
//         if (!empty($info['stock'])) {
//         $stock = (int) $info['stock'];
//     }
//   }
//     if ($stock === 0) {
//         $err_msg = '申し訳ございませんが、現在在庫切れです。';
//         return $err_msg;
//      }
//  }

// }

function complete_check_insert($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_update($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function complete_check_change($link) {
    $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
    return $complete_msg;
}

function validation_check($link) {
  $err_msg = [];
  if (!isset($_POST['new_name']) || (isset($_POST['new_name']) && $_POST['new_name'] === ""))  {
     $err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_price']) || (isset($_POST['new_price']) && $_POST['new_price'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_price'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '値段は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!isset($_POST['new_stock']) || (isset($_POST['new_stock']) && $_POST['new_stock'] === "")) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫を入力してください';
    } else if(preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['new_stock'])) !== 1) {
     $err_msg[] = '在庫は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (!empty($_POST["new_status"])) {
    if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 2) {
     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください'; 
    }
    }
return $err_msg;
}

function validation_check2($link) {
    if (!empty($_POST["update_stock"])) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',($_POST['stock'])) !== 1){ 
     $err_msg = [];
     $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
     return $err_msg;
    }
    

}
 }
```

tool.php

```
<?php
$data = [];
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $err_msg = validation_check($link);
     if ($err_msg == [])   {
        $data = insert_item($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_insert($link);
    }
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['renew'])) {
    $err_msg = validation_check2($link);
    if ($err_msg == [])  {
        $data = update_drink($link);
        var_dump($data);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_update($link);
    }
    
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
        $data = change_drink($link);
        $complete_msg = complete_check_change($link);
    }
    if (count($err_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p> 
    <?php }
    }
    
    if (count($complete_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ((array)$complete_msg as $comp) { ?>
            <p><?php print $comp; ?></p> 
    <?php }
    }
$data = do_sql($link);
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');

close_db_connect($link);
```

tool2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');?>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" /><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>
                <?php 
                if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ((array)$data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <!--<td><img class="img" src="<?PHP print $list['path']; ?>"></td>-->
                            <!--<td class="d_name"><?php print $list['drink_name']; ?></td>-->
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <!--<input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個-->
                                    <!--<br>-->
                                    <input type="submit" name="renew" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" name="change" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit"  name="change" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php print $list['id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

const.php

```
<?php
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];
$data = [];

define('DB_HOST',   ''); // データベースのホスト名又はIPアドレス
define('DB_USER',   '');  // MySQLのユーザ名
define('DB_PASSWD', '');    // MySQLのパスワード
define('DB_NAME',   '');    // データベース名

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');  // HTML文字エンコーディング
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');   // DB文字エンコーディング

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Comment: 作ったSQLが正しいかどうかはvar_dump($sql)した結果をphpmyadminのSQLタブで実行すればわかると思いますが。何かエラーはでますか？

Comment: 追加しました。ご確認のほどよろしくお願い致します

Comment: エラー文などは可能な限り画像ではなくてテキストで追記してください

Comment: またitemテーブルの構造もテキスト（CREATE文が望ましいです）で質問に追記してください。

Comment: 承知いたしました。

Answer (score 2):

idのフィールドに [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/example-auto-increment.html) の設定がされていないため、
idにデフォルトの0を代入しようとして、Primaryによりはじかれてます。

リファレンスに習いAUTO_INCREMENTをつけてみましょう。

ヒントとして上記ページの

> AUTO_INCREMENT に関する詳細の参照先を次に示します。
>
> - カラムに AUTO_INCREMENT 属性を割り当てる方法: セクション13.1.17「CREATE TABLE構文」、およびセクション13.1.7「ALTER TABLE 構文」。

という部分があると思いますので、その先のページで設定の仕方を確認してみましょう。

デバック方法の基本として、うまく動かないことが発生したらまずはPHPなのかMySQLの問題なのか区別して、MySQLの問題であればSQLをMySQLで実行しながらSQLの作成＆デバックを行いましょう。
うまくSQLが動くようになったらそれをPHPで作成するようにプログラミングします。